# send p5.js image to server

Tags: image-processing, server, p5.js

I captured an image from `createcapture()` through a webcam. Using `image()`, I got the image onto the canvas. Using `saveframes()`, and a callback, I was able to send the image to a server, but the image size is very big and I want the image to be `100 x 100` pixels every time whatever may be the size of image from `saveframes()` before sending it to server.

```
var x = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
var y = window.innerHeight * 0.75;
function setup()
{
    cnv = createCanvas(x, y);
    videoInput = createCapture(VIDEO);
    videoInput.size(x, y);
    videoInput.hide();
}
function draw()
{
    if (videoInput) {
        image(videoInput, 0, 0, x, y);
    }
} 

function image()
{
    saveFrames('out','png',1,1,
        function(im) {
            console.log(im);
            console.log(typeof im[0]);
            // image Data is stored in im[0].imageData
            // convert the image to smaller size
            data.imageData = im[0].imageData;
            // data.imageData = Math.random();
        }
    );
    $.post('addname',data,function(result) {
        console.log("data sent", result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you resize the image before you send it to the server?

Comment: yes..i want to do the resize before sending to server..but how??